# amcharts4 getting map elements to link to URL using polygon property

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

The following (while call `core.js, maps.js, animated.js` and a contextual `countryLow.js` file renders a map with polygons of regions (or sub-administrative districts):

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4maps.MapChart);
chart.geodata = am4geodata_franceLow;
chart.projection = new am4maps.projections.Miller();

var polygonSeries = chart.series.push(new am4maps.MapPolygonSeries());
polygonSeries.useGeodata = true;
polygonSeries.applyOnClones = true;
polygonSeries.fill = am4core.color("#a791b4");
polygonSeries.fillOpacity = 0.8; 
polygonSeries.strokeOpacity = 0.3;

var regionTemplate = polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template;
regionTemplate.tooltipText = "{name}";
regionTemplate.properties.fillOpacity = 0.8; 
regionTemplate.propertyFields.fill = "color";
regionTemplate.propertyFields.url = "url";
regionTemplate.columns.template.url = "http://localhost:3000/go/cities?region_id={properties.id()}"
```

While the tooltip is being revealed, how can one get the polygon to be clickable while passing the polygon's ID value as a parameter to the URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write zeroin code in Javascript instead of typescript and you will not have the error ;

```
regionTemplate.url = "http://www.amcharts.com/";
regionTemplate.adapter.add("url", function(url, target) { return url + "?id=" + target.dataItem.dataContext.id; }):
```

Answer (score 3):

[You can use placeholders in URLs.](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Placeholders_in_URLs) E.g.:

```js
regionTemplate.url = "http://localhost:3000/go/cities?region_id={id.urlEncode()}"
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/30dc8cb2bcdef6a2d5f11d41db1e58a1

Answer (score 2):

You can use adapter to modify original url, like:

```
regionTemplate.url = "http://www.amcharts.com/";
regionTemplate.adapter.add("url", (url, target)=>{
   return url + "?id=" + target.dataItem.dataContext.id;
})
```

Comment: scirpt does not compile ` SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (>)`  for the rocket after target.  Though it does execute!

Comment: @Jerome that function is written in ES6, it's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or `=>` "fat arrow". [Most browsers support it now](https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) with the exception of IE. Not sure what you mean by "script does not compile".

Comment: @notacouch  the browsers may support it, but the compilation process of javascripts - I believe rails gem `uglifier` - doesn't digest it.  Both your answer and @luca 's do however pass muster.

Comment: @Jerome Ah okay, that's what I was looking for. Thanks for the clarification. These days all we see are things like webpack, rollup, etc. environments that one way or another pass settings to Babel so minifiers can process. So it's nice to see different setups and what kind of errors they get when a little ES6 is slipped in.